# How do I combine hundreds of folders using command line

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, merge

I have 535 folders (`recup_dir.1`, `recup_dir.2`, ..., `recup_dir.535`) and I want to merge (combine?) the contents of those folders into a single folder (lets say a folder named `recup_dir`). Some files might have identical names (like `img.jpg`), they should't overwrite the existing ones (instead they should be renamed to something like `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg` and so on...).

Is there a way to do such thing using the command line?

Comment: are they all .jpg?

Comment: no, they have all kinds of extensions.

Comment: I have never tried this, but it seems like you should be able to **copy** the files using the `cp` command with the `--backup` option. The backup option can specify various types of backup file naming, including numbered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script below moves all files from one directory, containing your 535 folders, (recursively) into another (single) directory, keeping their original filename.

*In case of duplicates*

(Only) in case of duplicate names, files will be renamed to `duplicate_1_[filename]`, `duplicate_2_[filename]` etc.

#### How to use

Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `rearrange.py`, set the correct paths to the source and destination (directories) and run it by:

```
python rearrange.py
```

*The script:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/path/to/sourcedirectory"
target_dir = "/path/to/destination" 
# ---------------------------------------------------------
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        n = 1; name_orig = name
        while os.path.exists(target_dir+"/"+name):
            name = "duplicate_"+str(n)+"_"+name_orig; n = n+1
        newfile = target_dir+"/"+name; shutil.move(subject, newfile)
```

#### For (gnome-) terminal- "drag and drop" functionality:

Use below version, save it as described above (but don't change anything) and make it executable. To use it, open a terminal window, drag the script over the terminal window, then the source directory, last the destination. The command you'll then see in your terminal:

```
rearrange.py /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Press return and it is done.

*The script:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil
import sys
# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = sys.argv[1]
target_dir = sys.argv[2]
# ---------------------------------------------------------
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        subject = root+"/"+name
        n = 1; name_orig = name
        while os.path.exists(target_dir+"/"+name):
            name = "duplicate_"+str(n)+"_"+name_orig; n = n+1
        newfile = target_dir+"/"+name; shutil.move(subject, newfile)
```

#### Copy instead of move

If you'd like to keep your current directory untouched and only *copy* the files into a new directory, simply replace the last (section of) line:

replace:

```
shutil.move(subject, newfile)
```

by:

```
shutil.copy(subject, newfile)
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution. I had to run script with sudo and paths had to be absolute, but it worked... yeay :D
Now I have another problem - the destination folder now should contain ~267k files. For the last 30min I've been waiting for it to load, but it just keeps loading...

Answer (score 3):

**`sudo cp -r --backup=t recup_dir.*/* recup_dir`**

this command will copy the contents of all the 535 folder to `recup_dir` and rename existing files to **`file.~1~  file.~2~ ..`**

the 535 folder and their contents will still exist , if you want to delete them after copying just add **`&& sudo rm -rf recup_dir.*`** after the first command , so it will look like :

**`sudo cp -r --backup=t recup_dir.*/* recup_dir && sudo rm -rf recup_dir.`**

Comment: why would you use `sudo` here?

Comment: That's somewhat what I mentioned in my comment about the same time as your post.  I think it should work, although I would do the deletion after making sure the results were correct.  sudo is probably not needed if he has permissions for the files

Comment: in case the directory is protected , or one of the folders contains a protected file ,

Comment: because if it is the case , all file will be copied except the protected file and you will not be noticed at unless you use q verbose mode and search for errors ,

Comment: I get 'bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long'
There are over 500 files in each folder, could this be the cause?

Comment: yes this occur due the big number of argument to be executed in just one command , to avoid this issue you can paste this in your terminal :

`for folder in $(ls recup_dir.*); do sudo cp -r --backup=t $folder/* recup_dir; done`

this will not erase copied folder , to erase them in the same time when copying them use this one :

`for folder in $(ls recup_dir.*); do sudo cp -r --backup=t $folder/* recup_dir; sudo rm -rf $folder done`

,this may take a while due the big number of files you that you have!!

Comment: edit your answer with including this [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520924/how-do-i-combine-hundreds-of-folders-using-command-line/520936#comment708394_520936).